# Pause a Method/Prevent Balloon Tip from Displaying More Than Once

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

Here's my situation, I'm trying to create a system that when the network is down a balloon tip appears to tell me that it is down. But, by placing the balloon tip code inside of the event that's monitoring the network (every tick using a timer so basically a while loop) the balloon tip appears every tick whereas I only want it to appear once.

I have also tried using two separate timers and have the first one start the other and when there is a network failure, the balloon tip displays and then that timer stops. I then realised that "Thread.Sleep" stops the whole program as the code runs under one thread.

Is there anyway to stop a timer for X amount of seconds or pause just one method for X amount of seconds so the balloon tip only displays once?

Sorry for my explanation being so long-winded.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Just keep a bool variable, name it NetworkIsDown.  Only display the balloon when you change it from false to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a few things...

When you're polling (like in your while loop), it's good practice to use a different thread than the thread your program is executing in.  Otherwise, it'll lock the UI of your app.

I'd run the method that polls for network connectivity on another thread.  Once you do that, track whatever *the last network status was* in a variable, and update that variable whenever you get a result from polling for connectivity.

In your polling loop, if the previous connectivity result was that the network was connected AND your most recent connectivity result is that the network is down, then call a method (on yet another thread) which will display the balloon tip.

This method should display the balloon, sleep for X seconds, and then hide the balloon.

Make sense?

Comment: How would I compare if the variable was previously false against it now being true?

Comment: Create a variable (declared in your class, NOT the polling method) named LastPollResult and default it to false.  After you poll for connectivity, compare the new polled result to LastPollResult, take action based upon the comparison (if necessary), and then set LastPollResult to your new polled result.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts on it would be to approach it like this (pseudo code)

```
class Program
{
    public static bool hasBalloonOpened { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (network == down)
        {
            if (!hasBalloonOpened) 
            {
                hasBalloonOpened = !hasBalloonOpened;
                BalloonTip.Show();
            }
            //rest of loop or method calls
        }
    }
}
```

Basically a public Boolean that tells the loop whether it needs to open a balloon tip, if it does it flips the public boolean so the tip won't fire or show again.